# Главная страница домена

Tags: linux, сервер

Есть http сервер со всеми сертификатами, но проблема в том что на главной странице весит phpmyadmin с паролем и https не работает, это если зайти по ип или через http://домен. Как сделать другую главную страницу что-бы заработал https?

Comment: добавьте тэг той платформы, которая обрабатывает http-запросы: nginx, там, или еще что..

Comment: @AlexeyR. куда именно добавить, в файл какой-то или куда?

Comment: в вопрос. потому что не понятно что вы используете в качестве сервера.

Comment: @AlexeyR. на сервере установлен апачи

Comment: админа попросите исправить)